# How to remove first or last item from array and create new arrays?

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I have an array which contains random integers like `{2,3,4,7,8,9}` . I have to retrieve 2 arrays like following which contain:

- `{2,3,4,7,8}` (remove the last no)
- `{3,4,7,8,9}` ( remove the first no)

how can i do this in vb, any suggestions ?

Comment: So you want to clear values and then concatenate the 2 arrays?

Comment: no..I want only clear value and show in a loop .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Dim numbers As Int32() = {2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9}
Dim noFirst As Int32() = numbers.Skip(1).ToArray()
Dim noLast As Int32() = numbers.Take(numbers.Length - 1).ToArray()
```

These are LINQ methods so you need at least .NET 3.5 and `Imports System.Linq`.

If you don't want to use LINQ; this is more efficient but less readable:

```
Dim noFirst(numbers.Length - 2) As Int32
Dim noLast(numbers.Length - 2) As Int32
Array.Copy(numbers, 1, noFirst, 0, noFirst.Length)
Array.Copy(numbers, noLast, noLast.Length)
```

Comment: It's worth adding MIcrosoft's Reactive Framework Team's "Interactive Extensions" (NuGet "Ix-Main"). You get further operators like `.SkipLast(...)` among many others.

Comment: @TOM: `New String("234789".Skip(1).ToArray())`

Comment: @TOM: in that case you can also use string methods: `"234789".Substring(1)`

Answer (score 2):

The answer given is correct ; I'm just showing another way to achieve the same which don't suffer from the copy overhead (by use of `ToArray` or `Array.Copy`) and can be interesting in various scenarios.

Using the (underrated) [ArraySegment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9cc4bx8k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) struct (which is basically a pointer to the original array, the start offset and the count)

```
Dim numbers = { 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9 }
Dim exceptFirst = New ArraySegment(Of Int32)(numbers, 1, numbers.Length - 1)
Dim exceptLast = New ArraySegment(Of Int32)(numbers, 0, numbers.Length - 1)
```

*As a side note, just keep in mind changes in the original array will be visible from the ArraySegment (because it's just a wrapper around it)*